# Split lines against polygons in a PostGIS trigger

Tags: postgresql, trigger, functions, plpgsql, postgis

I have a table of lines, named `segment`, stored in the `reference` schema, and a table of polygones named `communes` in a `donnees_externes` schema. I try to create a trigger that split the features of `segment` on `communes` features on update of `geom` field or insert of a new `segment`.
Two situations:

- insertion: the new feature should be split on the boundaries of `communes` polygons, and each line resulting should have some attributes of the polygon it's part of
- update: the existing feature should continue to exist, its id should not change, but it should have a new geom split on polygons boundaries, and new attributes if necessary. New features should be inserted in the same table for each new polygon the `NEW` geometry intersects.

My code below updates the existing feature accordingly, but lines that were supposed to be inserted in the table aren't. I think it has something to do with the way I handle the returns of the function, but I tried many combinations without success.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_segments_on_communes_and_update_collectivities_codes() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN
        SELECT c.insee_com AS insee_com,
               '0' || c.insee_dep AS insee_dep,
               c.insee_reg AS insee_reg,
               c.code_epci AS code_epci,
               (ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(NEW.geom, c.geom))).geom AS geom,
               (ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(NEW.geom, c.geom))).path[0] AS "path",
               NEW.id_statut,
               NEW.propriete,
               NEW.author,
               NEW.create_date
          FROM donnees_externes.commune c
          WHERE ST_Intersects(NEW.geom, c.geom)
    LOOP
        IF rec."path" = 1 OR rec."path" IS NULL THEN
            NEW.geom = rec.geom;
            NEW.code_reg = rec.insee_reg;
            NEW.code_dep = rec.insee_dep;
            NEW.code_epci = rec.code_epci;
            NEW.code_commune = rec.insee_com;
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO reference.segment (geom,
                                           id_statut,
                                           propriete,
                                           code_epci,
                                           code_dep,
                                           code_reg,
                                           author,
                                           create_date,
                                           code_commune)
            VALUES (
                   rec.geom,
                   NEW.id_statut,
                   NEW.propriete,
                   rec.code_epci,
                   rec.insee_dep,
                   rec.insee_reg,
                   NEW.author,
                   NEW.create_date,
                   rec.insee_com);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER split_segments_on_communes_and_update_collectivities_codes
 BEFORE INSERT
    OR UPDATE OF geom
    ON reference.segment
 FOR EACH ROW
 WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() < 1)
 EXECUTE PROCEDURE split_segments_on_communes_and_update_collectivities_codes();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the `path` definition in that line: `(ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(NEW.geom, c.geom))).path[0] AS "path"`.

Here is the correct way to do it:

```
WITH parts AS (
            SELECT c.insee_com AS insee_com,
                   '0' || c.insee_dep AS insee_dep,
                   c.insee_reg AS insee_reg,
                   c.code_epci AS code_epci,
                   (ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(NEW.geom, c.geom))).geom AS geom,
                   NEW.id_statut,
                   NEW.propriete,
                   NEW.author,
                   NEW.create_date
              FROM donnees_externes.commune c
             WHERE ST_Intersects(NEW.geom, c.geom)
        )
        SELECT *,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS "path"
          FROM parts
```

And the full function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reference.split_segments_on_communes_and_update_collectivities_codes()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
rec RECORD;
newgeom geometry;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN
        WITH parts AS (
            SELECT c.insee_com AS insee_com,
                   '0' || c.insee_dep,
                   c.insee_reg AS insee_reg,
                   c.code_epci AS code_epci,
                   (ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(NEW.geom, c.geom))).geom AS geom
              FROM donnees_externes.commune c
             WHERE ST_Intersects(NEW.geom, c.geom)
        )
        SELECT *,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS "path"
          FROM parts
    LOOP 
        IF ST_GeometryType(rec.geom) != 'ST_Point' THEN
           IF rec."path" = 1 THEN
              NEW.geom := rec.geom;
              NEW.code_reg := rec.insee_reg;
              NEW.code_dep := rec.insee_dep;
              NEW.code_epci := rec.code_epci;
              NEW.code_commune := rec.insee_com;
           ELSE
              INSERT INTO reference.segment (geom,
                                             id_statut,
                                             propriete,
                                             code_epci,
                                             code_dep,
                                             code_reg,
                                             author,
                                             create_date,
                                             code_commune)
              VALUES (
                     rec.geom,
                     NEW.id_statut,
                     NEW.propriete,
                     rec.code_epci,
                     rec.insee_dep,
                     rec.insee_reg,
                     NEW.author,
                     NEW.create_date,
                     rec.insee_com);
           END IF;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$
;
```